# node-pre-gyp install--fallback-to-build --library=static_library

Tags: python, node.js, npm

I have a node.js app. Every time that I execute `npm` install on my app, the following error persists:

```
> grpc@1.20.0 install C:\Users\PC\Desktop\New folder\node_modules\@firebase\firestore\node_modules\grpc
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library

node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/grpc/v1.20.0/node-v72-win32-x64-unknown.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for grpc@1.20.0 and node@12.13.1 (node-v72 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
gyp ERR! find Python
gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python2" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python2" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python3" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python3" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if the py launcher can be used to find Python 2
gyp ERR! find Python - "py.exe" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Python27\python.exe
gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Python27\python.exe" could not be run
gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Python37\python.exe
gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Python37\python.exe" could not be run
gyp ERR! find Python
gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
gyp ERR! find Python You need to install the latest version of Python.
gyp ERR! find Python Node-gyp should be able to find and use Python. If not,
gyp ERR! find Python you can try one of the following options:
gyp ERR! find Python - Use the switch --python="C:\Path\To\python.exe"
gyp ERR! find Python   (accepted by both node-gyp and npm)
gyp ERR! find Python - Set the environment variable PYTHON
gyp ERR! find Python - Set the npm configuration variable python:
gyp ERR! find Python   npm config set python "C:\Path\To\python.exe"
gyp ERR! find Python For more information consult the documentation at:
gyp ERR! find Python https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation
gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
gyp ERR! find Python
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Python installation to use
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.fail (C:\Users\PC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:307:47)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.runChecks (C:\Users\PC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:136:21)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Users\PC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:225:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.execFileCallback (C:\Users\PC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:271:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at exithandler (child_process.js:302:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.errorhandler (child_process.js:314:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:270:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18363
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\PC\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=C:\\Users\\PC\\Desktop\\New folder\\node_modules\\@firebase\\firestore\\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\node\\extension_binary\\node-v72-win32-x64-unknown\\grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=C:\\Users\\PC\\Desktop\\New folder\\node_modules\\@firebase\\firestore\\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\node\\extension_binary\\node-v72-win32-x64-unknown" "--napi_version=5" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v72"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\PC\Desktop\New folder\node_modules\@firebase\firestore\node_modules\grpc
gyp ERR! node -v v12.13.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\PC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=C:\Users\PC\Desktop\New folder\node_modules\@firebase\firestore\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v72-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=C:\Users\PC\Desktop\New folder\node_modules\@firebase\firestore\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v72-win32-x64-unknown --napi_version=5 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v72' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\PC\Desktop\New folder\node_modules\@firebase\firestore\node_modules\grpc\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:210:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18363
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\PC\\Desktop\\New folder\\node_modules\\@firebase\\firestore\\node_modules\\grpc\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\PC\Desktop\New folder\node_modules\@firebase\firestore\node_modules\grpc
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v12.13.1
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.12.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\PC\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=C:\Users\PC\Desktop\New folder\node_modules\@firebase\firestore\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v72-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=C:\Users\PC\Desktop\New folder\node_modules\@firebase\firestore\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v72-win32-x64-unknown --napi_version=5 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v72' (1)
npm WARN pllanet@1.4.0 No repository field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! grpc@1.20.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.20.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\PC\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-05-20T01_25_02_113Z-debug.log
```

The engines I am using are:

```
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.16.3",
    "npm": "6.x"
  },
```

And the dependencies I am using are:

```
    "body": "^5.1.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "camelcase": "^5.0.0",
    "dotenv": "^6.2.0",
    "eslint": "^5.15.3",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.12.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-sslify": "^1.2.0",
    "extend": "^3.0.2",
    "firebase": "^5.11.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^7.4.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.3.1",
    "force-secure-express": "^1.0.1",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.0",
    "parser": "^0.1.4",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "pug": "^2.0.4",
    "socket.io": "^2.3.0",
    "ssl-express-www": "^3.0.6",
    "twilio": "^3.37.1"
```

I tried to install to the latest version or uninstall grpc, and it did not help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Switch to node V11.15.0 (your package.json engine node v10 is not taken into account, the error logs mention node v12). You can use nvm to do so, so you don't have to unstall node v12.
`nvm install v11.15.0`
then
`nvm use v11.15.0`
then
`yarn install`
That worked for me.